# We can't install yum update on centOS

Tags: centos8

Hi everyone am new to linux when am running alma linux. In my whm terminal when i run yum update i get this error below.

> CentOS-8 - Base                                                                      24 kB/s | 282  B     00:00
>
> Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'BaseOS': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried

I tried this solution listed but didnt work out .

Step 1: Go to the /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory.

Step 2: Run the below commands

```
sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
```

Step 3: To clean all cached information, use the following command

```
yum clean all
```

Step 4: Now run the yum update

```
yum update -y
```

> CentOS-8 - Base                                                                      24 kB/s | 282  B     00:00
>
> Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'BaseOS': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried

Comment: CentOS 8 End of life 'Dec 31 - 2021' : Examples edited repo files → https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cqafM9dnGZNgUBm5ozKNR9EhOkFbLLEs ............ Or migrate to Rocky Linux https://docs.rockylinux.org/guides/migrate2rocky/

Answer (score 1):

It might be because of the BaseOS broken repository.

```
# vim /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Linux-BaseOS.repo
```

change `enabled=1` to `enabled=0`

or

remove the file /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Linux-BaseOS.repo

Now update

```
#yum update -y
```